# Compiling Hadoop Java Files in Windows through Command line

Tags: hadoop

I just downloaded hadoop version 2.8.0 and wrote a simple java program that just imports a hadoop package I want to compile it using command line but when I do I get a message saying the package doesn't exist.
My hadoop is installed in root c drive. I just wanted to know how to get to those packages so that my program compiles successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.
I just needed to include hadoop-common-2.8.0.jar file while compiling.